# VBA Macro button placed in worksheet 1 to run macro inside hidden worksheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I do have a code that remove column "A" if any cell in this column value = ID. It works ok. I manage to place another code to run this macro (stored in worksheet "Remove_Column_A")using button placed on other worksheet of the same workbook. It works ok.

Problem I have is that:

1. I want to have this worksheet hidden all the time, whenever I do hide it - macro show error 1004
2. I also want, after macro is run using button, UI will stay on same worksheet where button is placed and
   worksheet "Remove_Column_A" is closed and hidden.

```
Sub Remove_column_A_if_contains_ID_macro_run_from_another_sheet()
    'below code will run macro inside worksheet "Paste SM" using button on another worksheet.

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Paste SM")
    ws.Select
  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
    'below code will remove column A if any cell value = ID
    Set P = Range("A1:A1")
    For Each cell In P
        If cell.Value = ID Then cell.EntireColumn.Delete
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `Select` - instead, fully qualify the `Range` with the `Worksheet` object.

```
Sub Remove_column_A_if_contains_ID_macro_run_from_another_sheet()
'below code will run macro inside worksheet "Paste SM" using button on another worksheet.

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Paste SM")
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
    'below code will remove column A if any cell value = ID

    Set P = ws.Range("A1:A1")
    For Each cell In P
      If cell.Value = ID Then cell.EntireColumn.Delete
    Next cell
End Sub
```

It does seem a bit odd to be looping thru a range consisting of only 1 cell, but maybe there's more to this code than in your post.

Comment: I don't see `ID` in your code is referring to. Shouldn't there be something like `dim ID as range` `set ID = sheets("hidden worksheet you're referring to")`?

Comment: True it is not defined or set anywhere, but it could very well just be a global variable that is set to a number for all anyone knows. `ID` wouldn't be a sheet object in this case as it is being compared to a cell value. What's important is that he says "it works" for him when the sheet is not hidden.

Comment: True. I'm missing a `application.screenupdating = true` after deletion. Maybe it works, but doesn't show?

Comment: are you the person asking the question then?

Comment: Sorry, I see I'm commenting to your answer rather than the actual question.

Comment: @braX - Thanks mate, it works fine as expected. It remove column as required, whether  worksheet is hidden or not and stays on same worksheet as button.